# JavaScript add another row in atable for unique id showing NAN value for id

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I have a html table. Inside that my markup is like this:

```
<table id="invoices-product-detail">
  <tbody id="tableToModify">
    <?php
      $i=1;
      while($i<2){
    ?>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="hidden" name="prdid[]" id="prd_id<?php echo $i; ?>" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="prdcost[]" id="prd_cost<?php echo $i; ?>" value="0" disabled="disabled" style="color:#333;" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="prdquentity[]" id="prd_quentity<?php echo $i; ?>" tabindex="<?php echo 3+($i*5);?>" onKeyUp="calprice1(this.value,'<?php echo $i; ?>');" value="1" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="prddamount[]" tabindex="<?php echo 5+($i*5);?>" readonly="true" id="prd_damount<?php echo $i; ?>" onKeyUp="calprice2(this.value,'<?php echo $i; ?>');"  />
      </td>
      <td id="readonly">
        <input readonly="readonly" name="prdprice[]" id="prd_price<?php echo $i; ?>" value="0" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <?php
    $i++;
    }
    ?>
  </tbody>
</table><!--#invoices-product-detail-->
```

Now under that I have a button called <kbd>Add a new line</kbd>:

```
<input type="button" onClick="createRow();"  value="Add a new line"></span>
```

in js file I have the `createRow()` function like this

```
function createRow() {
  var newlineno = document.forms[0].elements["prdprice[]"].length;
  newlineno++;

  var row = document.createElement('tr'); 
  var col1 = document.createElement('td');
  var col2 = document.createElement('td');
  var col3 = document.createElement('td'); 
  var col4 = document.createElement('td');
  var col5 = document.createElement('td'); 
  var col6 = document.createElement('td'); 
  var col7 = document.createElement('td'); 
  
  row.appendChild(col1); 
  row.appendChild(col2);
  row.appendChild(col3); 
  row.appendChild(col4);
  row.appendChild(col5); 
  row.appendChild(col6);
  row.appendChild(col7); 
  
  col1.innerHTML = "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"prdid[]\" id=\"prd_id"+newlineno+"\" /><input type=\"text\" name=\"prdname[]\" id=\"prd_name"+newlineno+"\";
  col2.innerHTML = "<input type=\"text\" disabled=\"disabled\" name=\"prddesc[]\" id=\"prd_desc"+newlineno+"\" />";
  col3.innerHTML = "<input type=\"text\" disabled=\"disabled\" name=\"prdcost[]\" id=\"prd_cost"+newlineno+"\" value=\"0\" />";
  col4.innerHTML = "<input type=\"text\" name=\"prdquentity[]\" id=\"prd_quentity"+newlineno+"\" onKeyUp=\"calprice1(this.value,'"+newlineno+"');\" value=\"1\" />";
  col5.innerHTML = "<select name=\"prddtype[]\" class=\"discount-type\" id=\"prd_dtype"+newlineno+"\" >"+document.getElementById("prd_dtype0").innerHTML+"</select>";
  col6.innerHTML = "<input type=\"text\" name=\"prddamount[]\" id=\"prd_damount"+newlineno+"\" onKeyUp=\"calprice2(this.value,'"+newlineno+"');\"  />";
  col7.innerHTML = "<input type=\"text\" name=\"prdprice[]\" id=\"prd_price"+newlineno+"\" class=\"price-input-text\" disabled=\"disabled\" value=\"0\" />";
  var table = document.getElementById("tableToModify"); // find table to append to
  table.appendChild(row); // append row to table
 }
```

Now here everything is fine. As per js I can easily add another row. But when I checked the id of input fields I saw that the first row (default one) is showing `<input type="text id="prd_name1">` which one is fine. But when I clicked to the add a new line and the new created line id was `<input type="text" id="prd_nameNaN">`. But here I want the id should be like `<input type="text" id="prd_name2">` and for 3rd row `<input type="text" id="prd_name3">` like so on. Here for every new created row the number of row will be added to every field id. Here can someone kindly tell me why this issue is here? Any help and suggestions are highly appreciable.

Comment: After you call var newlineno = document.forms[0].elements["prdprice[]"].length inspect what newlineno is. You may have to get the number of elements a different way. Such as jquery, $('.specific-class-only-for-product-names').length;

Comment: Check out the highlighting of your JavaScript in your posting. The line beginning with `col1.innerHTML =` breaks syntax highlighting, as it is missing a `"` near the end.
While this won't be the cause of your problem, it could cause you other problems later on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`document.forms[0].elements["prdprice[]"]` will only return a single DOM element if there is only one instance on the page, therefore calling `.length` on this will return `undefined`:

```
var newlineno = document.forms[0].elements["prdprice[]"].length; // Undefined
newlineno++; // NaN
```

Use querySelectorAll if possible instead:

```
var newlineno = document.querySelectorAll("[name='prdprice[]']").length
```

See this fiddle demonstrating three inputs: http://jsfiddle.net/Blade0rz/3Eyba/

And this one demonstrating one: http://jsfiddle.net/Blade0rz/kqakC/

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the variable `newlineno` is not a Number, that's what `NaN` stands for. check that the following line creates an actual number:

```
var newlineno = document.forms[0].elements["prdprice[]"].length;
newlineno++;
console.log(newlineno); // open Firefox' Firebug or a similar tool to see the output of this variable
```

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do id add a parseInt() function around the newlineno variable to convert it into an integer value.I had the same problem and and it got solved like this

var size = parseInt(document.getElementById(disease+"members").value);

and probably you should use .value instead of .length

example:
   var newlineno = parseInt(document.getElementById("prdprice").value);

or make some changes to the above example and it might work for you.